# Get and then export CSV Row Data to strings (android)

Tags: android, string, csv, sharedpreferences, http-get

I have a csv file that my app downloads from the internet, and then parses. But whenever I actually parse the csv file, my app force closes with an error at the line "Band = RowData[1];", as well as at line 1. I have never dealt with CSV files before so it would be helpful if someone could tell me how to properly get the row data of a CSV file and make the row data into strings. Here is where the CSV file is located: http://www.beaconschool.org/~markovic/lincoln.php

And how can I make it so it reads everything on my CSV file and adds all of that to the shared preferences file?

Additionally it does seem to be somewhat working, as it produces this shared preferences file, which contains the following content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="title">""</string>
    <string name="band">"ZQ11ISF1"</string>
    <string name="description">""<br>""</string>
    <string name="data">""</string>
    <string name="class">"INSTRUCTIONAL SKILLS"</string>
    <string name="number">"1"</string>
    <string name="teacher">"MARKOVIC"</string>
    <string name="date">""</string>
    <string name="type">""</string>
</map>
```

Here is the code in my app that gets and parses the CSV file, attempting to turn the row data into strings

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.beaconschool.org/~markovic/lincoln.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";



    try {
        Log.d("receiver", "animation stopped and downloaded file");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          response.getEntity().getContent()

                )


                );


            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                 Data = RowData[0];
                 Band = RowData[1];
                 Number = RowData[2];
                 Class = RowData[3];
                 Teacher = RowData[4];
                 Title = RowData[5];
                 Date = RowData[6];
                 Type = RowData[7];
                 Description = RowData[8];


                 SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("due_today", Context.MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();

                 localEditor.putString("data", Data.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("band", Band.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("number", Number.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("class", Class.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("teacher", Teacher.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("title", Title.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("date", Date.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("type", Type.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("description", Description.toString());

              localEditor.apply();

            Log.d("receiver", "information given to shared preferences");

            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
```

And here is the logcat

```
06-28 01:21:24.662: W/dalvikvm(7808): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
06-28 01:21:29.442: W/dalvikvm(7808): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41665ce0)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808): Process: com.bernard.beaconportal, PID: 7808
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at com.bernard.beaconportal.Due_Today_Fragment$Update.doInBackground(Due_Today_Fragment.java:232)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at com.bernard.beaconportal.Due_Today_Fragment$Update.doInBackground(Due_Today_Fragment.java:1)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-28 01:21:29.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7808):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: What is the length of rowdata..?? Seems like you are getting array index out of bound exception there...

Comment: By length do you mean number of characters?

Comment: Take a look at what data is actually in the string, looks like you have no commas in your line.

Comment: No... Number of elements comma separated.. try system.out.println(rowdata.length); if it is 9 or more, then no issues... Else you have to check your source data.....

Comment: Also try printing the value of line before using line.split.

Comment: Hmm, could it have something to do with the items being separated by ","  but instead the parser has them separated by only a comma. Also this should loop a number of times as I have multiple instances of the same variable.

Comment: So it returns 49 when I add System.out.println(RowData.length);, after the last RowData. It won't let me add it before line.split however since RowData hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Since it's definitely way over 9 elements separated, how would I go about making it so I don't get an out of bounds error? Is their a library that would better fit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you can try something like this!

```
String RowData[] = line.split(",");
int noOfItems = RowData.length;
int counter=0;
Data =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Band =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Number =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Class =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Teacher =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Title =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Date =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Type =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
counter++;
Description =  counter<noOfItems ? RowData[counter] : "";
```

The above code will check if array contains value and gives the value of the rowData if available. Else, it will assign a null ("") value to the string. The null value can be replaced with any appropriate value like, "No Data Available" or "NA" or the like.

Answer (score 1):

So you are accessing second item when the size of `RowData` is 1:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

Are you sure you are getting correct size of `RowData` after splitting?

```
String[] RowData = line.split(",");
```

Put a check before retrieving items of `RowData`:

```
if (RowData.length > 1) {
    Band = RowData[1];
}
```

Do the same for other assignments.

Comment: if size of rowdata is more than 1, will i still be able to retrieve it?

Comment: No. That is why you need to put the check.

Comment: So how can I make it so it reads everything on my CSV file and adds all of that to the shared preferences file?

Comment: So after trying what you said, it seems to only take the last rows of the csv file and a lot of the information is cut off.

Comment: Apply breakpoints and debug to see why the data is not coming in the expected form.